# Conversion of JSON to Java Pojo using MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

How to convert an incoming JSON object structure to Java Pojo using mapstruct?

The incoming JSON response object structure might be different as per the configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about conversion from JsonNode? Or some other JSON structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a moment MapStruct hasn't this functionality. I know, that they are working on mapping from object to JSON. Mb they are also working on opposite conversion.